# useState does not function correctly with Material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, use-state

I have an array of objects which I'm filtering over it to display a specific data whenever I select a value using material ui, but the issue is that in the first select it works and makes the filter and shows me the desired values but in the second render it does not show me anything:

data.js

```
export const testData = [
    {
        cl: 'peper',
        cln: 'a',
    },
    {
        cl: 'tomatoas',
        cln: 'a',
    },
    {
        cl: 'peper',
        cln: 'a',
    },
 {
        cl: 'tomatoas',
        cln: 'a',
    },
];
```

App.js:

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([...testData])
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')

    const filterValue = (value: any) => {
        if (value) {
            const filtered = data.filter(d => value === d.cl)
            setData(filtered)
        } else {
            setData([...testData])
        }
    }

const columns = [
        {
            title: 'cl',
            field: 'cl',
            filterComponent: (props: any) => {
                return (
                    <FormControl>
                        <InputLabel>vegetables</InputLabel>
                        <Select onChange={e => filterValue(e.target.value)}>
                            <MenuItem value={'peper'}>peper</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={'tomatoas'}>tomatoas</MenuItem>
                        </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                )
            }
        },
        { title: 'cln', field: 'cln', filtering: true },
]
 return (
        <div className="App">
            <MaterialTable
                columns={columns}
                data={data}
                options={{
                    filtering: true
                }}
            />
            Selected: {value}
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filtering array based on each letter from input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64674657/filtering-array-based-on-each-letter-from-input)

Comment: No, it did not actually :(

Comment: The concept is still the same. If it is a derived data, it should not be stored as a state. The state should be the selected filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter to your testData array rather than your data state array.  First time it works because it is initially set as [...testData] but after that is already filtered.  So when you run the filter again you are running a filter on filtered data.

Try running the filter on testData instead.

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([...testData])
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')

    const filterValue = (value: any) => {
        if (value) {
            const filtered = testData.filter(d => value === d.cl)
            setData(filtered)
        } else {
            setData([...testData])
        }
    }
```